# XSLT: SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to execute the below code but ended up in the below exception.

javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Code is:

```
<xsl:when test="/result/DECODE='CANCELLED'">
    <xsl:variable name="match_dates" >
        <xsl:for-each select="/legacyresult/*[starts-with(name(), 'END-DT')]">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number"
                      select="concat(substring(.,7, 4),substring(.,4, 2),substring(.,1, 2))" order="descending" />
            <xsl:variable name="end_dt" select="." />
            <xsl:variable name="match" select="count(/legacyresult/*[starts-with(name(), 'EFF-DT')][text()=$end_dt])" />
            <xsl:if test="$match=0" >
                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
                <xsl:text >,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="final_date" >
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($match_dates, ',')" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/legacyresult/*[starts-with(name(), 'END-DT')][.=$final_date]">
            <xsl:sort select="substring(name(),13,2)" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:variable name="prodSeq" select="substring(name(),13,2)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="id">ID<xsl:value-of select="$sq"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="product">
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$id"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="productId">0<xsl:value-of select="/legacyresult/*[name() = $id]/."/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:when>
```

Please let me know what is wrong in the above code. I have cross checked the tags. But i unable to find the issue.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is in this fragment of code? Presumably this exists as part of some larger file, since a stylesheet can't have `<xsl:when>` as its outermost element?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you have the following error:

```
        <xsl:variable name="id">ID<xsl:value-of select="$sq"/>
        </xsl:variable>
```

The first line has a `/` at the end, making it omni, but you're also closing a variable tag that doesn't start anywhere. Either remove the closing tag or the trailing `/` of the first line.

Comment: That seems to be the end tag of the an earlier variable, namely final date. So the </xsl:variable> should be moved up to the appropriate line.

Comment: Not how I see it. After `final_date` has a `for-each` inside. After the `for-each` closing tag, the `variable` for `final_date` is closed.